# iPhone: Real-time video color info, focal length, aperture?

Tags: iphone, avfoundation, core-video

Is there any way using AVFoundation and CoreVideo to get color info, aperture and focal length values in real-time?

Let me explain.  Say when I am shooting video I want to sample the color in a small portion of the screen and output that in RGB values to the screen?  Also, I would like to show what the current aperture is set at.

Does anyone know if it is possible to gather these values?  Currently I have only seen that this is possible with still images.

Ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AVCaptureStillImageOutput will get you a real time still from the video stream, including exif data for focal length, aperture, etc. Color info you could calculate yourself from that bitmap.

Comment: I am developing an iOS application and I need to get the same information as Nic Hubbard (exif data, especially for focal length).
I am unable to get this value from AVCaptureStillImageOutput, I tried a lot of stuff founded on SO and other website.
I asked a question here : 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22142395/how-to-get-exif-data-from-avcapturestillimageoutput
If you can have a look a it, would be very very helpful for me!

Comment: The focal length is fixed but differs from product models. As another user posted, ifixit.com may have that information available @Humbertda

Answer (score 1):

AVFoundation, CoreVideo, and CoreMedia include support for getting a video bitmap in "real-time".  From there you can process a portion of the RGB pixels however you want.

I don't know of any current public iOS API to get you the aperture.

The focal length is fixed, but differs between product models.  ifixit.com might have that info.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the aperture by:- `camera.lensAperture` 
this will give the aperture of the camera of iPhone whichever you selected