# FOV in exif data in UImages?

Tags: ios, camera, swift3

I'm looking through the EXIF data on a photo I converted into UImage format. Is there anything in there that reveals the FOV? I can see various lens details and suspect there may be some way to get the details from that?

The issue for me is that the photos I'll be using may not have originated on the iPhone camera, so I would like some way of getting the FOV back out without hard coding it.

Comment: Try to check here, maybe is helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22142395/how-to-calculate-fov

Comment: It looks like Canon and Apple are the only two cameras that will work. Arg! Thanks for the link.